# Как оформить такой код через класс?

Tags: javascript

```
function chain(arr) {
    function wrapChain(func) {
        return function(...args) {
            arr = func.call(null, arr, ...args)
            return this;
        }
    }
    return {
        take: wrapChain(self.take),
        skip: wrapChain(self.skip),
        map: wrapChain(self.map),
        reduce: wrapChain(self.reduce),
        foreach: wrapChain(self.foreach),
        filter: wrapChain(self.filter),
        value: () => arr
    };
}
class Chain extends CustomArrayFunctions {
    constructor(arr) {
        super();
        this.arr = arr;
        return this;
    }
    wrapChain(func){
        return (...args)=>{
            this.arr = func.call(null, this.arr, ...args);
            return this;
        }
    }
    take(){
     return this.wrapChain(super.take);
    }
}
```

Интересует именно функция wrapChain,
сделал что-то похожее но не робит